# Combination Keypad in Unity

Tags: c#, unity

Im having a slight problem in getting my Combination keypad to work. Ok so basically I'm using gameObject buttons to use for the numbers 0-9. So each gameObject button has a number link to it. The combination passcode is found by finding items, in which these items have link numbers to them as well, hence item.password. The problem Im having trouble with is for the combination to show if its correct or incorrect and also if you push one of the buttons 5 times it will show incorrect code. Please help if you can Here is the code:

This is where I will have the mouse click on the button to declare a password digit.

```
public class RayCasting : MonoBehaviour
{
public float pickupDistance;
public List<Item> items;
public List<Keybutton> buttons;


// This is for the KeyPad Buttons Area


    foreach(Keybutton button in buttons)
    {

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            if (button.gameObject.Equals(hit.collider.gameObject))
            {
                hit.transform.renderer.material.color = Color.red;
                    button.ButtonWasClicked(button.currentCombination);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

This is where the magic works. This is basically the gears of the combination to work. It suppose to get the 5 combination numbers from my Item class password variable and implement them to make the combination. The thing is that Im not sure if that works plus if I hit one gameObject button 5 times it says incorrect passcode.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Keybutton
{
public GameObject gameObject;
private int Combination;
public int currentCombination;
private int buttonClickProgress;

public void  ButtonWasClicked (int buttonNmb){
Item item = new Item ();

Combination = item.password;
buttonClickProgress++;
currentCombination = buttonNmb;

if(buttonClickProgress < 5){    
    decimal d = (decimal)currentCombination / 10;
}
else{
    if(currentCombination == Combination){
        Debug.Log("Correct Passcode");
        buttonClickProgress = 0;
        currentCombination = 0;
    }
    else{
        Debug.Log("Wrong Passcode, reseting...");
        buttonClickProgress = 0;
        currentCombination = 0;

        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
}   
}
```

Any ideas? I know its a lot but feel free to ask whatever you need.

Comment: I get that the code is a "number" but unless you plan on performing numeric operations it might be best to use a string.  This way you can `+=` each new key, and use `String.Length` instead of maintaining a progress counter.

Comment: So with every int varibale in the KeyPad class I should make it a string?

Comment: Would I have to change my entire int format into string? Because just making the class KeyPad into a string would definitly error out the entire script. Is there a possible way in just keeping it in numerical format?

Answer (score 1):

The traditional approach to these situations is to use a string based password.

```
string currentCombination = ""

public void  ButtonWasClicked (string newKey){
    currentCombination += newKey;

    if (currentCombination.Length == correctCombination.Length) {
        if(currentCombination == correctCombination) {
            //correct combo!
        }
        else {
            //bad combo!
        }
    }
}
```

---

However you have opted for an int based approach but the implementation does not seem to store the previous button presses to build a complete code.

I would expect the following change to help:

```
//Change from this:
//currentCombination = buttonNmb;

//To this:
currentCombination = (currentCombination * 10) + buttonNmb;
// shift the existing numbers left then place new one on the right.
```

I have no idea what is intended by this line but it currently doing nothing of consequence:

```
decimal d = (decimal)currentCombination / 10;
```

It is declaring and assigning a value to a local variable.  It will only remain in scope for that clause (the if block) and the value will be forgotten next time the method is called.

---

In the future one of the easiest way to do light debugging of issues like this is to print the value of you variables to the console.  If you add the following line to the end of this method you will be able to see is the code is being built correctly or not.

```
 Debug.Log(currentCombination);
```

If this doesn't provide enough information then setting a breakpoint and setting though the code will usually find the problem.

Comment: I see whatcha mean but one thing about it is that in order to get the correct combo, they will be getting that from item.password. Which is an int. And this item.password int is also randomized as well 0-9.

Comment: Should I just put my entire script up here so you can see what I'm talking about? Maybe that will help out a bit.

Comment: Nope with doing currentCombination = (currentCombination * 10) + buttonNmb; it just multiplies the digit, it doesnt move one decimal place over.With this line of script decimal d = (decimal)currentCombination / 10; it does. Plus it still not storing itself. Any other ideas??

Comment: What is the value of a "correct combination"?

Comment: The value is public so basically one number from 0-9 for each button.

Comment: Ok i think it works and Im glad you told me to Debug my "correct Combination". Because for some reason some of the objects and the number are mixed up.